# How to search for protected questions

Tags: support

I would like to know is there any way to search for protected questions like duplicate etc.

From advanced search:

```
status  closed:yes
        duplicate:no
        migrated:no
        wiki:no
```

I have tried:  [protected:yes](https://askubuntu.com/search?tab=votes&q=protected%3ayes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: you can't; such operator is not mentioned anywhere in [How do I search?](https://askubuntu.com/help/searching) and there's a [pending feature-request for that on Meta.SE since 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52825/302251).

However this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/403738/protected-questions) seems to be working (`topn` = number of questions to be shown in the results).